# Super newb - Android Studio emulator throws INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

I'm literally on day one of learning some Android development.  I downloaded the latest Android Studio on my Mac. Set it up. Walked through a small code example aaaand... it failed. I pushed the "play" button and it launches the emulator but then throws the error:

```
09/18 14:33:12: Launching 'app' on Nexus 5X API 29 x86.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
APK signature verification failed.
```

There are several postings here that cover this error, but they are either very old and don't match anything I am looking at, or are a level of complexity that I don't really understand.  The tutorial and stuff online all suggest that something this simple should just "work".  I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Oh man ok I figured it out.  NONE of these tutorials explain that you have to create a keystore. Including the tutorials that even walk through setting up Android Studio. So a fresh install requires you to go "Generate Signed Bundle/APK" and the wizard walks you through setting up a basic keystore.